# RPY2 to use as.xts from XTS library

Tags: python, r, xts, rpy2

I am using RPY2 in python to call as.xts object from xts library. 'as' is a reserved word in python. Hence, i am unsure how to proceed use as.xts in my python code.

My aim is to use as.xts on an existing dataframe with time series column.

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
r_dataframe = pandas2ri.py2ri(pandas_df)
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
xts= importr('xts', lib_loc="local path to R library" , robject_translations = {".subset.xts": "_subset_xts2", "to.period": "to_period2"})  
r_ts = as.xts(r_dataframe) # i am unsure of this step usage.
```

i expect a time series object in output of the last line of code. I am going to use forecast package on top of time series object.

Comment: Instead of using `as.xts`, use `xts` and specify which columns contain the data and which is the time series column. `xts(r_dataframe[ , columns], by = r_dataframe[ , timeseries])`

Comment: Thank you. Now, i am getting another error.
`r_ts = xts(r_dataframe["X_source.value"], by = r_dataframe["X_source.timestamp"])
`
Error - File "D:\projectname\venv\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\vectors.py", line 1200, in __getitem__
    tmp = rinterface.ListSexpVector.__getitem__(self, i)
TypeError: SexpVector indices must be integers, not str`

.Also the data type of columns X_source.timestamp, X_source.value is 'POSIXct' & 'numeric' .

Comment: I did another change in code.  `r_ts = xts(r_dataframe[1], by = r_dataframe[0])`. Now, i get error "TypeError: 'InstalledSTPackage' object is not callable". It's like an unending road.........